# varnish caching of POST requests

Tags: http, solr, varnish

What I'm doing is mildly insane, but since GET requests have very strict size limit, solr uses POST requests to `/solr/select` URL to do what is "semantically" a GET.

I'm trying to put varnish in front of solr to do some caching. I put this in `vcl_recv` function:

```
 if (!(req.request == "GET" || req.request == "HEAD" ||
     (req.request == "POST" && req.url == "/solr/select"))) {
     /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
     /* Modified to support POST to /solr/select */
     return (pass);
 }
```

and varnish now tries to handle that except it automatically converts a POST to a GET.

I'm aware all of that is fairly ridiculous and far from any best practices, but in any case, is there an easy way to use varnish this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing the req.POST into a GET, and transform the POST data to GET parameters (you probably would have to use inline-C) and do a lookup / fetch.

This GET request limit from the HTTP spec is not necessarily implemented by either Varnish or your back-end server. As you don't depend on intermediate caches and User-Agents outside your control to handle long urls, you could give it a try.

Comment: I haven't put it all together yet, but Tomcat has configuration parameter for max HTTP request size, and solr is happy with 64kB URLs, so it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working after reading this [tutorial from](https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/caching-post-requests/).

What the tutorial doesn't say is that there is a bug in one of the required VMODS when using with Varnish 4.1, this bug has the effect that the first POST request is passed to the backend with a truncated body.

I solved this by using Varnish 5 and works like a charm.

If you want to give it a try I have a Dockerfile for this:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

LABEL maintainer lloiacono@*******.com

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache varnish \
    && apk add git \
    && git clone https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules.git \
    && apk add automake && apk add varnish-dev \
    && apk add autoconf && apk add libtool \
    && apk add py-docutils && apk add make \
    && cd varnish-modules/ \
    && ./bootstrap && ./configure && make && make install

COPY start.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-app-start

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-app-start

CMD ["docker-app-start"]
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -xe

varnishd -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m
varnishlog
```